# Calculating specificity of multiple selectors on one rule

Tags: css

The following CSS code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #box1 div.spec2 p,
    #box1 #box2 p {
        color: blue;
    }

    #box1 #box3 p {
        color: green;
    }
</style>
```

both rules are targeting the element `<p>` and the text in it has `green` color.

I thought it should be `blue` because there are 3 `ids`, 1 `class` and 2 `tags` in the first rule and there are only 2 `ids` in the second rule.
However, the specificity calculated by the website https://specificity.keegan.st/ shows that:

- the first rule has specificity (0,1,1,2)
- the second rule has specificity (0,2,0,1)

My question is how the `specificity` is calculated for multiple selectors (the first rule)? Why it only has 1 `id`?

Comment: It doesn't work that way. The specificity is determined for each selector (separated by commas). You cannot simply sum the number of IDs in comma separated selector list. `#box1 #box2 p` has the same specificity as `#box1 #box3 p`. The specificity of `#box1 div.spec2 p` is calculated independently of `#box1 #box2 p`.

Comment: @Terry thx for your answer. However I didn't find any document explain how multiple selectors' specificity is calculated. Would you please provide some reference? And why `#box1 div.spec2 p` is chosed over `#box1 #box2 p`'s specificity?

Comment: You are simply grouping the selectors. By grouping them you do not influence their specificity. The [comma-separated notation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html%23id-selectors) is simply a shorthand to declare the same styles that apply to multiple selectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect your confusion comes from the assumption that when you group multiple selectors, you can manipulate the specificity of the selectors that are contained within the comma-separated list. This is not true: the comma-separated selector list is simply a shorthand to declare the same styles that are applied to all your selectors.

In other words:

```css
#box1 div.spec2 p,  /* Specificity: 0, 1, 1, 2 */
#box1 #box2 p {     /* Specificity: 0, 2, 0, 1 */
    color: blue;
}

#box1 #box3 p {     /* Specificity: 0, 2, 0, 1 */
    color: green;
}
```

...is actually **equivalent to**:

```css
#box1 div.spec2 p { /* Specificity: 0, 1, 1, 2 */
    color: blue;
}

#box1 #box2 p {     /* Specificity: 0, 2, 0, 1 */
    color: blue;
}

#box1 #box3 p {     /* Specificity: 0, 2, 0, 1 */
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: :D I get it now! And I suspect the result `(0,1,1,2)` given by that website is only a little drawback of its algorithm? The real answer should be `(0,1,1,2)` and `(0,2,0,1)`?

Comment: The tool only evaluates selectors **singly**. If you have selectors group together in a comma-separated list, you need to evaluated them individually.